# How to create a dateTime with a specific day - ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, razor

I'm working in ASP using MVC 4, and i try to create a date with a specif day. For example, the user insert day `19`, and i in controller will create a date `19/02/2014` for example...

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new `DateTime` as follow:

```
var myDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 19);
```

Also see the MSDN on [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And if you would like to create a controller action which results the date by day, try the following:

```
public ActionResult GetDate(int day)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var myDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, day);
    return Content(myDate.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you:

```
var input = 19;
var d= new Date(2014,2,input);
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime has a constructor which will take a year,month,day

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 19);
```

You can replace 19 with your variable from your ViewModel.